# How to set GNU Indent input

Tags: linux, gnu-indent

I use GNU `indent` and I want using `bash` script to give a command that takes as input all my C files(`*.c`, `*.h`) and gives output these files formatted with Indent.

My command line is

```
indent | find -regex '.*/.*\.\(c\|h\)$' | xargs
```

Is not working,it stacks.

Comment: Think a bit about the order of commands in a pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly passing the arguments to `indent` command. Your command is just left waiting for inputs over standard input but you haven't provided any. May be your intention was to run the command on each result from the `find` command, which should have been written as

```
find -regex '.*/.*\.\(c\|h\)$' -print0 | xargs -0 indent
```

In pure `bash` you just need to pass them as positional parameters. If the source and header files are in a directory, without nesting, a simple glob expansion would suffice

```
indent *.c *.h
```

For multi-level directory structure, you can use `find`

```
find -regex '.*/.*\.\(c\|h\)$' -exec indent {} +
```